# Como optimizar codigo de actualizacion formulario - VBA

Tags: excel, lista, vba

Buenos dias muchachos!

Estoy trabajando en un excel con Alta/Baja/Modificación de pedidos. Hasta el momento mi código funciona perfectamente, el problema es que a la hora de modificar y actualizar un registro (adjunto foto) mi codigo demora mucho en ejecutarlo! Sinceramente hace poco tiempo que hago código y me gustaría perfeccionarlo (y adquirir buenas prácticas) con su ayuda!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez que el usuario realiza las modificaciones y clickea en actualizar pedido se ejecuta esta macro.

```
Private Sub GestionPedido_Click()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim rango, rangodetalle As Range
Set WS = Worksheets("BD_PEDIDOS")
Set WSD = Worksheets("BD_DETALLE")
Dim filapedido, ii As Integer
Dim PrecioAnterior As Double
Dim strTitulo As String
'ALERTAS
strTitulo = "Modificar pedido"
Continuar = MsgBox("Desea modificar el pedido?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, strTitulo)

If Continuar = vbNo Then Exit Sub

idbuscada = Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 0)
'RANGO DE PEDIDOS
Set rango = WS.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
filapedido = rango.Rows.Count
'RANGO DE DETALLES PEDIDOS
Set rangodetalle = Worksheets("BD_DETALLE").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
filadetalle = rangodetalle.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To filapedido
    For ii = 2 To filadetalle
        If LCase(WS.Cells(i, 1).Value) = LCase(idbuscada) Then
            'RELLENO COLUMNA DE SITUACION DE ENTREGA
            If entrega_enviado = True Then
                WS.Cells(i, 3).Value = entrega_enviado.Caption
            Else
                WS.Cells(i, 3).Value = entrega_noenviado.Caption
            End If
            'RELLENO COLUMNA DE SITUACION DE COBRO
            If cobro_pago = True Then
                WS.Cells(i, 10).Value = cobro_pago.Caption
            Else
                WS.Cells(i, 10).Value = cobro_adeuda.Caption
            End If
            
        'RELLENO COLUMNA DE OBSERVACION PEDIDO
        WS.Cells(i, 5).Value = Me.txtobs
        
        'CAMBIOS EN BANDEJAS/CAJONES
        If LCase(WSD.Cells(ii, 1).Value) = LCase(idbuscada) Then
        PrecioAnterior = WSD.Cells(ii, 5).Value / WSD.Cells(ii, 4).Value
        TotalViejo = WS.Cells(i, 6).Value
            If WSD.Cells(ii, 2).Value = "Champiñon" And WSD.Cells(ii, 3).Value = "COMPRA BANDEJA" Then
                Call Importes(PrecioAnterior, Me.txtCHb.Value, ii, i, TotalViejo)
            End If
            If WSD.Cells(ii, 2).Value = "Champiñon" And WSD.Cells(ii, 3).Value = "COMPRA CAJON" Then
                Call Importes(PrecioAnterior, Me.txtCHn.Value, ii, i, TotalViejo)
            End If
            If WSD.Cells(ii, 2).Value = "Champiñon" And WSD.Cells(ii, 3).Value = "COMPRA CAJON GASTRO" Then
                Call Importes(PrecioAnterior, Me.TxtChGastro.Value, ii, i, TotalViejo)
            End If
            If WSD.Cells(ii, 2).Value = "Portobello" And WSD.Cells(ii, 3).Value = "COMPRA CAJON" Then
                Call Importes(PrecioAnterior, Me.txtPTn.Value, ii, i, TotalViejo)
            End If
            If WSD.Cells(ii, 2).Value = "Portobello" And WSD.Cells(ii, 3).Value = "COMPRA CAJON GASTRO" Then
                Call Importes(PrecioAnterior, Me.TxtPrGastro.Value, ii, i, TotalViejo)
            End If
            If WSD.Cells(ii, 2).Value = "Portobello" And WSD.Cells(ii, 3).Value = "COMPRA BANDEJA" Then
                Call Importes(PrecioAnterior, Me.txtPTb.Value, ii, i, TotalViejo)
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next ii
Next i
'MENSAJE FINAL
MsgBox "PEDIDO MODIFICADO CON EXITO!", vbInformation, strTitulo
End Sub
```

Yo creo que el mayor problema de mi código es que le hago recorrer dos ciclos for, pero no se como realizarlo de otra manera.

Las tablas que utilizo para buscar los datos son las siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya les agradezco su ayuda! Muchas gracias y buena semana

Comment: Hola. ¿Has probado añadiendo `Application.ScreenUpdating=False` al principio de tu código, y `Application.ScreenUpdating=True` al final?

Comment: Hola Elier! si he probado pero no encuentro diferencias en los tiempos de ejecucion

Comment: Otra opción sería que una vez que hayas modificado el pedido, entonces salgas del bucle. Tu bucle ahora mismo siempre mira todas las filas, pero en realidad, una vez que has terminado, deberías poder salir con un `Exit For`. Otra opción es irte directamente a la fila que te interesa, sin bucle, con `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` en vez de tanto bucle.

Comment: Genial Elier, me pondre a investigar estas dos opciones que me estas dando... muchas gracias!

Comment: y el código de `Importes()`? Puede que tengas ahí el problema. ¿Tiene algún `.Select` o `.Activate`?

Comment: Hola pollo, el codigo importes solamente actualiza los valores de importe.. me llevo los datos de filas y solamente reemplazo los valores ahi.